# Why bandwidth affects the noise floor level positively?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, noise

Bandwidth affects the noise floor level positively. See the relation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_detectable_signal). What exactly is the dynamics (mechanism) behind this relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. Noise power tends to be distributed equally across the frequency spectrum, at least for selected frequency bands. That is what thermal noise is.  So if you have more bandwidth. You will have more total noise power. The equation is basically

N = kTB, with k Boltzmann constant, T the temperature, and B the bandwidth.

Thermal noise is a good model, for most noise that is not close to the clock rate the shot noise for instance), up to the maximum bandwidth of the devices. So modeled typically a random white noise. If there are structures and other devices that makes it correlated or colored (i.e., non-white), often the way to deal with it is to filter out what you can, and equalize the rest so it looks white, and you can apply the normal equations for signal detection (signal plus white Gaussian noise, or sometimes with some other statistics that Gaussian like Raleigh or Chi square, etc) and parameter estimation

Now, you do want B higher if there is signal power that you can usefully use in detection. In radio and microwave spread spectrum signals cover more bandwidth, and the noise comes in from there, but through cross correlation with a matched filter you get down to a smaller detection bandwidth.

Lots of tricks you can play.

Comment: 1) What is shot noise? 2) Is it possible to read signals below noise floor?